# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() on Godaddy host

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writing some code to fetch data using prepared statements. Below is my code

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("select * from products where id =?");
$statement->bind_param('d',$id);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
$product_details = $result->fetch_all();
```

I am using `PHP 5.6`.This works fine on my `localhost` with no error. When I uploaded this file to my Godaddy Host this will gives error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

I searched over internet, but not found satisfied results, On stackoverflow I found several question similar to this but not got solution for me. 
On Godddy host I enabled `mysqld` extension and also running `PHP 5.6` So any help

Answer (score 0):

There might be issue with your $statement->execute(). try to run this code in try catch block, may be you find some exception. or run this method with if block.

```
if($statement){
    $result = $statement->get_result();
}
```

or

```
try{
   $statement = $connection->prepare("select * from products where id =?");
   $statement->bind_param('d',$id);
   $statement->execute();
   if($statement){
     $result = $statement->get_result();
   } 
   $product_details = $result->fetch_all(); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```